# how to show text in password character or masked for Password content for listview WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

How to show password column as password or masked for listview in WPF.

```
<GridViewColumn  Header="Password">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Password}" Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

I am using `Observable Collection` and user can change the password as well and I want to update after password update?

```
 _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person() {Id = 1, Name = "Bob", Age = 45, Password = "password1"},
            new Person() {Id = 2, Name = "Sarah", Age = 25, Password = "password2"},
            new Person() {Id = 3, Name = "Tim", Age = 40, Password = "password3"}
        };


 public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: show us the `Person` class as you've written it.

Comment: I added the person class as well

Comment: Check [PasswordBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: it's not working and showing nothing `<PasswordBox PasswordChar="{Binding Password}" Width="100"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `TextBox` component cannot bind to the `Password` variable as you expect unless you add a mechanism to notify the `TextBox` input's modifications back to the class instance.

Modify the class as follows:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    private string _password;
    public string Password { 
        get { return this._password, }
        set {
            if (value != this._password) {
                this._password = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
        string propertyName
        )
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(
                this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)
                );
        }
    }

}
```

This pattern tells the framework to bind the variable in both the directions: to the `TextBox` and from the `TextBox`.

Please, note that the above pattern is pretty verbose because matches the "old" Net Framework 4.5. Most recent versions of C#/Net allows a more compact coding style.

Comment: Thanks, any change required in xaml?

Comment: No, you binded the TextBox's Text and the Password properties together: they are now synchronized.

Comment: I suspected that, and other users commented that way. The PasswordBox is what you are looking for, but it has a special behavior (due security), and it won't work easily with this approach. Consider an imperative approach, without binding to XAML.